# How to create a class to close GUI and exit Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to find a way to do this for a while to no avail. I would like to create a class to completely close my GUI in tkinter and I'm not having much luck. I've tried sys.exit and .destroy() a few different ways. I can manage to do what I want without using classes but I'm rather new to OOP. Here is my code:

```
import sys as system
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class headerFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self._create_widgets()
    
    def _create_widgets(self):
        #header bar
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='#0066cc', highlightthickness=0, height=45, width=600)
        canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='Production Assistant', background='#0066cc', foreground='White', font=('calibri', 18, 'bold'))
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

class loginFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight =1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)

        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        #username
        ttk.Label(self, text='Username: ', justify='right').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        username = ttk.Entry(self, width=33)
        username.focus()
        username.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        #password
        ttk.Label(self, text='Password: ', justify='right').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        password = ttk.Entry(self, width=33, show='*')
        password.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        #add padding
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=0, pady=5)

class loginButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        #setup the grid layout manager
        self.columnconfigure(0, minsize=62)

        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        #buttons
        ttk.Button(self, text='Login', width=15).grid(row=0, column=1)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Forgot Login', width=15).grid(row=0, column=2)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Request Access', width=15).grid(row=1, column=1)
        ttk.Button(self, text='Exit', width=15, command=exitButton).grid(row=1, column=2)

        #add padding to buttons
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=3, pady=3)

class exitButton():
    def exit():
        #code to close gui and program       
        
#create the main application
class mainLogin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Login')
        self.geometry('325x175')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.configure(background='#444444')
        
        #windows only (remove the minimize/maximize buttons)
        self.attributes('-toolwindow', True)

        #TCL to center the screen
        self.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

        #layout on the root window
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self._create_Styles()
        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_Styles(self):
        #create styles
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('TFrame', background='#444444')
        s.configure('TLabel', background='#444444', foreground='white')
        s.configure('TButton', background='#878683', foreground='black')

    def _create_widgets(self):
        #create the header frame
        _header_frame = headerFrame(self)
        _header_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        #create the login frame
        _login_frame = loginFrame(self)
        _login_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.N)

        #create the button frame
        _login_button_frame = loginButtonFrame(self)
        _login_button_frame.grid(column=0, row=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = mainLogin()
    app.mainloop()
```

class exitButton() is what I would like to call from multiple different pages in the application to close everything.

Any help is appreciated, I'm trying to learn as I build so if you have any suggested reading based around Python that would help with this I would appreciate it!

Comment: This seems like a very odd request. Closing the app is usually a single function call. It's not clear what you mean by creating a class to do it.

Comment: On this page it really wouldn't need to do much more as it is just the login, I have other pages that on close I would like it to save a copy of any opened documents if there are any, and a few other tasks all as you click that button

Comment: What would be the difference to a normal function in your class?

Comment: i guess just the ease of calling this class from anywhere in the program (such as when this GUI isn't the present window, I know you're supposed to be able to call it through it's parent class but I'm new to OOP so I guess I'm not really sure what the best practice is.